# Importing custom module containing overloaded print function in python generating attribute error

Tags: python, import, overloading, python-import

I am using the Pycharm IDE. I am trying to import a file and that is causing an attribute error. I created a Python file testing.py:

```
    import decimal

    def print(num, round_digits=3):
            if (type(num) == float or type(num) == decimal.Decimal) and round_digits >=0:
                    __builtins__.print(round(num, round_digits))
            else:
                    __builtins__.print(num)
```

In the same directory, I wrote a file test.py:

```
    import testing

    testing.print(0.17 * 0.3064,2)
```

Running this file produces this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):

File "C:/Users/anura/PycharmProjects/pythonProject/test.py", line 3, in <module>
    testing.print(0.17 * 0.3064,2)

File "C:\Users\anura\PycharmProjects\pythonProject\testing.py", line 5, in print
    __builtins__.print(round(num, round_digits))

AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'print'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use [`builtins`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/builtins.html), not `__builtins__`. The content of `__builtins__` is an implementation detail.

So change your code to

```
import builtins    
import decimal

def print(num, round_digits=3):
    if (type(num) == float or type(num) == decimal.Decimal) and round_digits >=0:
        builtins.print(round(num, round_digits))
    else:
        builtins.print(num)
```

---

An additional suggestion: You might want to replace `type(num) == float` with `isinstance(num, float)`. [`isinstance`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/functions.html#isinstance) allows subclasses of the given class.

Comment: Thanks. I still don't get the difference between builtins and __builtins__.

Comment: According to the documentation `builtins` "provides direct access to all ‘built-in’ identifiers of Python". `__builtins__` is an internal detail. It might or might not be there and you shouldn't rely on it. Different implementations of Python (CPython, PyPy, ...) might use it differently (or not at all) and it could even change between Python versions. Just don't use it.